# How more efficiently can I write the test bench for a MOD 16 asynchronous counter using JK flip flop?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, testbench

```
////////// Code for jk flip flop  ////////////

module jkff_behavmodelling(q,q_bar ,clk, reset,j, k);

input wire j,k,clk,reset;

output reg q,q_bar;

always @(posedge clk) begin

  if(reset)

            begin
            q=1'b0;
            q_bar=1'b1;
            end 
  else 

    begin
          case({j,k})
            {1'b0,1'b0}: begin q=q;q_bar=q_bar; end
            {1'b0,1'b1}: begin q=1'b0;q_bar=1'b1; end
            {1'b1,1'b0}: begin q=1'b1;q_bar=1'b0; end
            {1'b1,1'b1}: begin q=~q; q_bar=~q_bar; end
          endcase
    end
 end
endmodule


////////////////////** code of mod 16 asyn counter **///////////////////////

module mod16asynCounter(q, q_bar, clk, reset, j, k);

output  [3:0] q; output  [3:0] q_bar;

  input clk,reset, j, k ;

 jkff_behavmodelling jk1 (q[0], q_bar[0], clk, reset, j, k);

 jkff_behavmodelling jk2 (q[1], q_bar[1], q[0], reset, j, k);

 jkff_behavmodelling jk3 (q[2], q_bar[2], q[1], reset, j, k);

 jkff_behavmodelling jk4 (q[3], q_bar[3], q[2], reset, j, k);

endmodule


/////////////////**test bench of mod 16 asyn counter**///////////////////

module mod16upc_tb_v;

    // Inputs

    reg clk;        reg reset;  reg j;  reg k;

    // Outputs

    wire [3:0] q;   wire [3:0] q_bar;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    mod16asynCounter uut 

(.q(q),.q_bar(q_bar),.clk(clk),.reset(reset),.j(j),.k(k));

    initial begin

        // Initialize Inputs
    clk = 1;    reset = 1;  j = 1;  k = 1;
    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
     #100   j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 0;    
     #100   j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 1;
     #100   j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 0;  
     #100   j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 1;  
     #100   j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 0;
     #100   j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 1;
      #100  j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 0;
      #100  j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 1;
      #100  j = 1'b1; k = 1'b1;  reset = 0;
 
end
always #50 clk <= ~clk;    
endmodule

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

[image: waveform of mod 16 im getting]

Answer (score 1):

As your waveforms show, your 4-bit counter is not counting properly.  When I run a simulation, I see that only `q[0]` is toggling between 0 and 1.  The other 3 bits (`q[3:1]`) are unknown (`x`) throughout the duration of the simulation.  This is due more to a problem with the design than the testbench.

Module `jkff_behavmodelling` implements a *synchronous* reset for your flops.  The `q[0]` flop is reset properly because it is driven by the testbench `clk` signal.  The `reset` signal is properly sampled at the posedge of `clk`, which sets `q[0]` to 0.  However, The `q[1]` flop is not reset properly because it uses the `q` output of the first flop for a clock, and the simulator is not properly sampling the `reset` signal.

To fix this, use an *asynchronous* reset signal.  Change:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
```

to:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
```

In the testbench, you simply need to deassert the `reset` signal once, instead of toggling the `reset` signal.  When we make these changes and let the simulation run long enough, we see `q` counting down from 15 to 0, then repeating the sequence.

```
initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    clk = 1;    reset = 1;  j = 1;  k = 1;
    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100 reset = 0;    
    #4000 $finish;
end
```

[image: waveforms]